# execution halted as the script is not able to read the file

Tags: r, compiler-errors, syntax-error, rscript

I am running a script in R using command: Rscript gtex_tiss_chrom.R 1
The content of this script is:

```
source("../code/gtex_v7_nested_cv_elnet.R")
"%&%" <- function(a,b) paste(a,b, sep='')

argv <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
chrom <- argv[1]

#tiss <- argv[1]
#chrom <- argv[2]

snp_annot_file <- "../output/snp_annot.chr" %&% chrom %&% ".txt"
gene_annot_file <- "../output/gene_annot.parsed.txt"
genotype_file <- "../output/genotype.chr" %&% chrom %&% ".txt"
expression_file <- "../output/transformed_expression.txt"
covariates_file <- "../output/covariates.txt"
prefix <- "Model_training"

main(snp_annot_file, gene_annot_file, genotype_file, expression_file, covariates_file, as.numeric(chrom), prefix, null_testing=FALSE)
```

the error:
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
Calls: main ... get_filtered_snp_annot -> %>% -> distinct -> filter -> read.table -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
cannot open file 'snp_annot.chrNA.txt': No such file or directory
Execution halted

Comment: Read.   `cannot open file 'snp_annot.chrNA.txt': No such file or directory Execution halted`

Comment: Yes, but I am passing the argument 1 which corresponds to snp_annot.chr1.txt

Comment: hum so your line `snp_annot_file <- "../output/snp_annot.chr" %&% chrom %&% ".txt"` should result in `:./output/snp_annot.chrsnp_annot.chr1.txt.txt"` ?  You paste chrom to the filename, so your argument should not be the file.  ?

Comment: It should be snp_annot.chr1.txt and not snp_annot.chrsnp_annot.chr1.txt.txt

Comment: ok so try `snp_annot_file <- chrom`.  You are trying to build a filename that you do not seem to want.

Comment: Yes, this works.

Comment: Great, I transferred our discussion to an answer, I would appreciate if you accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, here is the answer.

In the code:

1. `chrom <- argv[1]`: assigns the first argument to the `chrom` variable.
2. `snp_annot_file <- "../output/snp_annot.chr" %&% chrom %&% ".txt"`.  This will assign the filename `"../output/snp_annot.chr<VALUE OF CHROM>.txt"`.
3. If `argv[1]` is not assigned, chrom would be assigned NA.
4. Hence the filename is built as `"../output/snp_annot.chrNA.txt"`.
5. And that file does not exist, hence your error message.

The solution is to modify the code slightly:

1. If you want to pass the filename to the script, use: `snp_annot_file <- chrom`.
2. That way the value of the argument you used gets used directly.
3. OR you could hard code the filename in the scrip, depending on your requirement.

FYI:

1. The same applies to this second line: `snp_annot_file <- "../output/snp_annot.chr" %&% chrom %&% ".txt"`